# דוד or דויד why is David spelled differently in the tanach?

Tags: names, tanach, king-david, spelling-variants

Why is David's name spelled דויד and דוד ? with a י and without a י?

Comment: I believe MouseEvent is referring to Rashi's comment to Divrei Hayamim 1, (Ch.2, v.15). The Chida (Chomat Anach, ad loc.) gives an explanation based on Kabbala (not something I understand).

Comment: http://www.hidabroot.org/he/comment/reply/21886

Answer (score 2):

דוד is referring to King David. דויד is referring to Moshiach ben David specifically as Melech HaMoshiach. This is brought in Kol HaTor 2: 2. This is also brought in Be'er Yitzchok on Likkutei HaGra 63.

Comment: Can u provide a link? תודה

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because of david's friendship with Jonathan. A yud was added to David's name and a 'hei' to Jonathan's. To show that their great friendship had hashem's blessing.
Since these were 'additions' one doesnt use them in spelling their names. Although R Yehonasan  Eibeshuts did add the 'hei'.

I will have to look for the source.